# When and why would bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y) return -1?

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage

Just ran into a problem in my program. If I go back to a previous version in my code, even though there's no changes in the section which raises the problem, the program works fine.

Why would getRGB() method of BufferedImage return -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the description of `getRGB()` says, it returns a value in the default RGB model which is `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. In that color model it uses four bytes, one per channel, with the first channel being the Alpha channel which controls transparency. If you have an opaque white pixel, the ARGB value is `0xFFFFFFFF` with the first byte being `0xFF` to represent full opacity, which is why this method returns `-1`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-

Comment: I found the problem. Unfortunately, it was not related to the getRGB() method. I'm going to mark your response as the accepted answer.